# Can't install and import cv2 after installing opencv by all method

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

guys 
i am facing a problem from a while i want to install cv2 but i cant install or import it, coz i am getting an error. while importing im getting "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." and while installing  i am getting "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2'

i am using python 3.7 and installing using pip method on atom, its install opencv but its not working with cv2... i tried all the methods and when i am trying to install using .whl file  " Requirement 'opencv_python-3.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the
file does not exist
opencv_python-3.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform." [this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDyba.jpg)

Comment: Have you installed [Visual C++ redistributable 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)?

Comment: _yeah_ i did installed Visual C++ redistributable 2015